# Apache serve service from local host on subdomain

Tags: apache, hosting, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use Apache to serve multiple sites at the same time, the structure I want to obtain is composed by a main site at `example.com` and use the subdomains `radarr.example.com` and `sonarr.example.com` to access my Radarr and Sonarr servers.

The main site is hosted on **machine1**, I set up a virtual host using apache and certbot:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  
  WSGIDaemonProcess sflasksite user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webapp/app.wsgi

  <Directory /var/www/webapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup sflasksite
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /static /var/www/webapp/static

  <Directory /var/www/webapp/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/www/webapp/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/webapp/logs/access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The two servers I want to serve are on **machine2**, on the same network as **machine1**, how can I obtain the two services respectively on `radarr.example.com` and `sonarr.example.com`?

After some reading, I tried to use a **Reverse Proxy**, configuring a virtual host for each service as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  
  ServerAlias radarr.example.com

  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.20:7878/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.20:7878/

  ErrorLog /var/www/radarr/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/radarr/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and alike for Sonarr.

However, when I navigate to `radarr.example.com`, I do not get the expected service but the main site.

How can I get the reverse proxy to work? Or should I switch to another strategy altogether?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers should be asked on [sf]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the clarification, I'll ask this question on Server fault.